# Is it possible to replace a part of the settings application on Android?

Tags: android

I am building an application that will make it easier to manage certain settings on an Android device. For now it will just be a separate app in Android market.

But long term I would like the app to actually replace part of the Android settings app. Is it possible to have the app invoked or overwrite a certain part of the settings that the bundled app manages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported right now.